# reading .csv from zip file in lambda from aws s3 bucket

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a zip file in s3 bucket . I unzip that zip file in memory(without unzipping it) and dump the data in .csv into tables in my database.But while dumping the tables , i get foreign constraints as the program dumps the csvs in the order in which they come , so some tables are dumped before other table example - i have two tables 'dealer_master' and 'billing_master', structure of both tables:

1) dealer_data

- dealer_id : primary key
- country
- pincode
- address
- create_date

2) billing_data

- bill_id : primary-key
- dealer_id : foreign_key
- bill_amount
- bill_date

In the zip file , i get billing_data ahead of dealer_data. So get 'foreign key constraint error'. For the solution to above problem i turned off foreign key constraints while making connection to database. Is there any other way, i can dump the tables into my database in correct order ?
Can i store tables in memory for some piece of time and later dump them in the way i want ?

My code goes like this :

`def etl_job():`

```
`data = json.load(open('path_to_json'))`

 `logger = helpers.setup_logging()`

 `s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id=data['aws_access_key_id'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=data['aws_secret_access_key'])`  

`s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id=data['aws_access_key_id'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=data['aws_secret_access_key'])`  

`keys = []`  
`resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)`
`for obj in resp['Contents']:`        
   `keys.append(obj['Key'])
 for key in keys:
   names =  key.split("/")
   obj = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name).Object(helpers.zip_file_name())
 buffer = io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read())
 zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer,'r')
 logger.info("Name of csv in zip file :%s",zip_file.namelist())
 logs = ""
 dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
 for name_of_zipfile in zip_file.namelist():
    zip_open = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name_of_zipfile))
    zip_open = zip_open.dropna()
    table_name = "{name}".format(name=name_of_zipfile.replace('.csv',''))
    try :
        zip_open.to_sql(name=name_of_zipfile.replace('.csv',''), con=database.db_connection(), if_exists = 'append', index=False)
    except SQLAlchemyError as sqlalchemy_error:
        print sqlalchemy_error
 database.db_connection().execute('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;')`
```